# Ubuntu on VMWare Player: My Ruby is missing

Tags: vmware, ubuntu-11.04

I installed Ubuntu 11.10 on VMWare Player. The OS is running well.
I already installed ruby 1.9.2 and rails 3 too.

When I shutdown the VMWare player and turn on again, my installed ruby is lost. I don't know what makes it lost. Any help please?

Comment: Are you certain that VMWare player allows you to make persistent changes?

Comment: i am a newbie on this area. i don't know either if vmware player doesn't have persistent change. how do i check it?

Comment: Were _any_ changes that you made to the system retained? Or were they all thrown away? Does the properties for your virtual machine (or block device?) allow writing to the virtual machine or block device? Do you have permissions to modify the files that hold all the virtual machine data?

Answer (score 0):

check out your configuration.
All configurations are set in the *.vmx file
Open yourVirualmachine.vmx with notepad and check the snapshot.action entry. If it's set to snapshot.action = "autoRevert" no changes will be saved. Then change to snapshot.action = "keep"  this will solve your problem